# Possibility of getting information about Licences in use in BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We have a requirement from one of our clients to retrieve the information regarding licence usage from in BIM360. More specifically, they need to know how many licences are being consumed and who is using each one (who was the user that consumed it).

We have been all over Forge's documentation and it doesn't look like it has any endpoint serving licence-related requests, but we thought we would ask the community in case someone else faced this problem and found a solution. In case there's no solution, is there a webpage we can see this information on? We don't seem to be able to find that either, nor is our client.

**TLDR**; We need an endpoint to request licence information from Forge's API, if one such endpoint exists.

Comment: I'm checking that for you. Do you know which type of license your customer is using?

Comment: It's our client who is giving the licenses to third parties, but I can ask that for you.

Comment: "giving licenses", can you elaborate?

Comment: We are not sure, as we are not BIM360 clients (just developers using Forge's API). What they tell us is that some third parties are using licenses provided by them, and they would like to know who, which projects, and how many licenses are therefore being used.